# Unable to access "center" property of UIView from outside the class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, properties

I have an instance of `UICollectionViewCell` ( lets call it `c` ).
`c` has a property `child` of type `B*`

```
@property (strong) B* child;
```

in `B` there is a declaration

```
@property (strong) C* parent;
```

in `C.m` I set

```
self.child.parent = self
```

In `B.m` I have code :

```
position = self.parent.center.x;
```

For some reason I can not access `center` property of UIVIew from outside the instance. Is it private ? I looked in `UIView.h` and in the documentation. I dont see it being private.

Accessing `self.parent` in `B.m` is giving me the correct values ...

So why cant I access it ? In `C.m`

```
self.center
```

is working as expected ...

EDIT : With the real code

This is the so-called "C.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIMovableImage.h"

@interface LetterCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *letterCellView;

@end
```

This is "B.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class LetterCollectionCell;

@interface UIMovableImage : UIImageView
{
    CGPoint currentPoint;
}
@property (strong) LetterCollectionCell* parent;

@end
```

This is "C.m"

```
#import "LetterCollectionCell.h"
#import "LettersCollection.h"

@implementation LetterCollectionCell

-(void)PrepareImage:(int)index Hint:(BOOL)hint Rotate:(BOOL)rotate
{
    if ([_letterCellView respondsToSelector:@selector(parent)])
    {
       UIMovableImage* temp = ((UIMovableImage*)self.letterCellView);
       temp.parent = self;
    }     
}    

@end
```

And here is the "B.m"

```
#import "UIMovableImage.h"
#import "LetterCollectionCell.h"

@implementation UIMovableImage

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
        // Get active location upon move
        CGPoint activePoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.parent];

        // Determine new point based on where the touch is now located
        CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(self.parent.center.x + (activePoint.x - currentPoint.x),
                                       self.parent.center.y + (activePoint.y - currentPoint.y));

 }
@end
```

Please note that the LetterCollectionCell's letterCellView is of type UIImageView and not of type UIMovableImage. The reason is that I want to keep this declaration as a placeholder. In the Interface Builder I have two scenes where the LetteCollection is used. In one scene I set the imageview to be of UIMovableImage ( thru Inspector Window ) and at the other I left the image to be of type UIImageView. So the run-time will create the proper class upon different scenes and at the collection I check : if the image has a property "parent" - I set it up. Otherwise I dont.
It works fine, the assignment works just fine.... but the access is not

Comment: Don't declare a strong reference to `parent`, it'll create a retain cycle.

Comment: thanks, have no idea what that means yet but certainly gonna find out :)

Comment: I don't get what's wrong, your example builds correctly.

Comment: Could the downvoter or anyone care to explain the downvote and unupvote ? This is to understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason.
The whole question was barking at the wrong tree.
In fact, the bug was at the other place and I just kept looking at the "Invalid Expression" int the debugger's watch window.

To sum up : accessing the "center" property worked just find under the circumstances described in the original question. The "Invalid Expression" of the debugger and a bug in a different place made me chase a wrong thing.

I +1d the generally correct answers and comments but can not accept them since it may mislead people.

Thanks to all for the help and the effort

Answer (score 4):

The only reason you wouldn't have access to the property would be that the class is not aware of it (forward declaration).  Therefore, you must have a missing `#import "C.h"` in B's implementation file.

Perhaps an example is necessary to appease the downvoter, so let's use yours:

Here's what B's header should look like

```
//Give us the ability to subclass UICollectionViewCell without issue
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//forward declare a reference to class B.  We cannot access it's properties until we
//formally import it's header, which should be done in the .m whenever possible.
@class B;

@interface C : UICollectionViewCell

//Declare a child property with a strong reference because we are it's owner and creator.
@property (strong, nonatomic) B* child;

@end
```

Now C's header.

```
//import foundation so we can subclass NSObject without a problem.
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//Forward-declare classe C so we don't have to #import it here
@class C;

@interface B : NSObject

//keep an unretained reference to our parent because if the parent and the child have
//strong references to each other, they will create a retain cycle.
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) C* parent;

@end
```

Now that that's out of the way, here's the implementation of C that you are most likely using:

```
#import "C.h"
#import "B.h"

@implementation C

-(id)init {
    if (self =  [super init]) {
        self.child = [[B alloc]init];
        self.child.parent = self;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Not too bad, but here's the problem:

```
#import "B.h"

@implementation B

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        CGFloat position = self.parent.center.x; //ERROR!
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

because C's only declaration that it has a `center` property (or rather that it's superclass has a `center` property), and C's type are in the C.h file, B has no knowledge of C's properties without an explicit `#import` of C.h.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I can prove my response more thoroughly if need be.

Comment: this answer is correct given the information provided by the asker, and +1 for the weak reference to `parent`, the original code has a retain cycle.

Comment: CodaFi, thanks so much for the comment. But I have it exactly the way you proposed. I will paste my original code in a minute or two instead of the pseudo C and B ... +1 for the more than elaborate answer. I think your original statement about #import was enough to show the point. the -1 was unjustified in this case, AFAIK

Answer (score -1):

According to the sequence of your question it seems to me that you start with setting the C.m but on that line code the child instance is not set yet.. that self.child = nil so setting self.child.parent = self will give you no result... Accordingly on B.m will not have the access to the parent object...

if i am correct just set your child instance object -- self.child = B*    --- before set self.child.parent = self......

Comment: -1 It's not a matter of a null reference, it's a matter of not being able to access a property.

Comment: sorry, I am sure I set it in the correct order. I also stated that accessing self.parent gives me the correct value while self.parent.center at the same location in code gives the error